# Sanity - How to set timezones correctly?

Tags: localization, sanity, l10n.js

I set a date & time for an event with a `datetime` type, however its representation is skewed -2h.

I imagine that this is related to ha javascript l10n of datetime.

Could you help me to keep the right consitency?

[image]

Comment: If your question was answered, please mark it as answered?

Answer (score 3):

In the Sanity backend, all [datetime values](https://www.sanity.io/docs/datetime-type) are stored as UTC.

E.g. `happensAt: '2019-05-17T21:05:00.000Z'`.

However, the input field renders the timestamp as seen from the browsers timzone. So if your browser timezone is 2 hours after UTC, `2019-06-29T19:00:00.000Z` will render as `2019-06-29 21:00`.

In your case, if you want the `Program` document to [preview](https://www.sanity.io/docs/previews-list-views) with the browsers local time instead of the UTC value, you can override preview by grabbing the stored UTC value and creating a localized string representation. [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) might be of help:

```
const format = require('date-fns/format')
const utcDate = program.happensAt // '2019-05-17T21:05:00.000Z'
const stringToDisplay = format(new Date(utcDate), "HH:mm") // '23:05'
```

You may then use `stringToDisplay` in the [preview](https://www.sanity.io/docs/previews-list-views) of your document.

I can absolutely see that this behavior is unexpected, but I'm not 100% sure what the optimal/correct behavior is. Any suggestions greatly appreciated!